# Some applications absorb mouse events made by stylus so that I can't hook them

Tags: windows, touch, hook, stylus

My ultimate purpose is getting mouse move event from outside of my main window, and distinguish it was from mouse or stylus.

Before I ask my question, I want to notice what I already knew.

I used SetWindowsHookEx to hook mouse events.
The value - MSLLHOOKSTRUCT.dwExtraInfo I received, when I use stylus pen, it came as 0xFF515712. So I was able to distinguish mouse move and stylus move. At this time, there was nothing wrong.

The problem is that mouse event messages doesn't be raised when my stylus is on any other active window(ex. Chrome). There wasn't any message so nothing to confirm and analyze. But the stylus pointer(cursor) was on my desktop wallpaper, or on the main app, everything went well as I mentioned.

In my guessing, Windows 10 treat stylus movements on web browsing as another events not as mouse events. I want to hook them, but I don't know what kind of event they are.

The important thing you need to know is that this issue is not for every mouse event, but just for events from stylus device.

I really tried to search the solution, but there is no way but ask to you genius people. Please help me, you people already helped me a lot in many stack overflow pages, but I need you more, and your answering may help this project -> https://github.com/ladofa/thepen

---

Additional info.

I found specific programs that absorb mouse events from stylus.

- All browsers (Chrome, Edge, Internet Explorer) except the title bar of them.
- Calculator
- VSCode

Comment: My theory is that stylus events are processed prior to the messaging queue and if they are consumed, they do not enter the message queue—thus cannot be hooked.  http://users.erols.com/rwservices/pens/biblio03.html

Comment: VSCode was buit by Node js. Something that are opreating JavaScript makes this problem I guess.

Comment: VSCode is based on Electron, which is based on Google Chrome and Node.js.  Both of which are C/C++ and use the Windows event/messaging system.  The issue is certainly with Windows itself.  I have since discovered several other strange behaviors with using mouse movement to detect pen/touch events.  I've since started using WM_POINTERUPDATE (and associated UP and DOWN events).  Unfortunately wasn't able to globally hook this message successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Probably relevant, from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85) ("LowLevelMouseProc callback function"):

> If nCode is greater than or equal to zero, and the hook procedure did not process the message, it is highly recommended that you call CallNextHookEx and return the value it returns; otherwise, **other applications that have installed WH_MOUSE_LL hooks will not receive hook notifications and may behave incorrectly as a result**. If the hook procedure processed the message, it may return a nonzero value to **prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook chain or the target window procedure**.

(emphasis added)

Comment: Thank you for your attention and answer. But I've already done that you posted. Ah, If nCode is lower than zero, what value should I return? I'm always returning the result of CallNextHookEx. Do you think it makes some problem?

Comment: @ladofa What I meant is that I'm guessing that the other applications are preventing your code from receiving the hook because of this. I'm not sure how to solve it though... You'd need some way to get it before the other application does, or after despite its lack of passing it on.

Comment: Yeah, It may be true, thank you so much. But because I need some more attention for this issue, I'm hesitating to check it. You may understand me.

Comment: From few days ago, I thouht about this issue again. Sorry but your comment is wrong. Browsers not absorb EVERY mouse event but JUST event from stylus. VSCode makes same issue. Node JS and something may make this happen.

Comment: I don't believe this to be the case as the hook procedure (at least mouse down) doesn't get called in most applications when the stylus is being used.